Comparing values every 8th column in excel in an IF function
I need to compare the values of every 8th column, starting from the column Y, specifically checking if the value from row 13 is lower than the value from row 5. If that is the case in just one of the comparisons it should return "Yes" and "No" if it is always bigger. This means it should compare Y13 to Y5, AG5 to AG5 and so on.
So far I am at the point that I know how to check only every 8th row but the formula still returns incorrect values (i.e. yes when it is actually no):
=IF(OR(Y13:KKM13<Y$5:KKM$5;MOD(COLUMN(Y$5:KKM$5)-COLUMN(Y$5);8)=0);"Yes";"No")

At this point I am stuck and don't know how to continue. Can somebone help me?


Use row() to get the row number and add 8.

I can't follow your logic, can you please elaborate a bit further?

So what did you try?

I added the code I tried in the question.
I know that "MOD(COLUMN(Y$5:KKM$5)-COLUMN(Y$5);8)=0)" should let me check only every 8th column, but how can I ensure it specifically only compares Y13 with Y5, AG13 with AG5 and so on?

Clarification: "If that is the case in just one of the comparisons it should return "Yes" and "No" if it is always bigger" — should this be "If that is the case in at least one of the comparisons it should return "Yes" and "No" if it is always bigger".   (i.e. "just one" means "exactly one" — so if Y13 is less than Y5 and AG13 is less than AG5, then it is true for two of the comparisons, which is currently an undefined result)

Hi @Ricco, in the screenshot it looks like you're checking whether row 5 is less than 13,14 etc. ("Check if 5 lower than 13,14,...".) But in the question it is the other way around. Which is correct?

=IF(AND(FILTER(Y13:KKM13<Y5:KKM5,MOD(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Y13:KKM13)),8)=1)),"Yes","No")

Compares if Y13 is lower than Y5, AG13 lower than AG5, AO13 lower than AO5 and so on. If all comparisons are TRUE, returns "Yes" otherwise "No"
Change , to ; if needed depending on your Excel settings.

Thank you for your input. Unfortunately it's still not quite working correctly. May I ask what the purpose of the sequence function here is?

To numerate columns from 1st to nth in selected range. What exactly doesn't work? I think you should update your question with small data sample and desired output.

It returns no even though it should return yes in the first instance. I updated the question with a screenshot for better understanding.

I saw that you put "AND" in the formula. I am not sure if that is correct, since it should return Yes when at least one of the comparisons is true. But when I change "AND" to "OR" it only returns "Yes" which is also false.

Try this formula:
=LET(data,Y5:AO13,
every8thColumn,CHOOSECOLS(data,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(data)/8,1,8)),
first,CHOOSEROWS(every8thColumn,1),
second,CHOOSEROWS(every8thColumn,9),
IF(AND(second<first),"Yes","No"))

It retrieves every eighth column from the first row of the data section - same for second row to check. And then compares these values.


Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it does not work (I get the error "the first argument of let must be a valid name") and is not ideal for my use case. I need to also compare Y14 to Y5, Y15 to Y5 and so on for many rows, so the approach with the data unfortunately would not work well.

Is it possible to keep using the expression "MOD(COLUMN(Y$5:KKM$5)-COLUMN(Y$5);8)=0)" for this if statement?

What is your language? Maybe you have to use a semicolon for the formula instead of comma. Regarding I need to also compare Y14 to Y5, Y15 to Y5: you should state that in your question!

My excel is set to German. The semicolons did in fact resolve the issue but the returned value is still incorrect. The values I am comparing are percentages if that changes anything.
My apologies for not mentioning the Y14, Y15 etc directly in the question.

=WENN(SUMME(MMULT((REST(SPALTE(Y13:AO18);8)=1)*(Y13:AO18<Y5:AO5);ZEILE(1:17)));"Yes";"No")      Enter the formula with C+S+E if you work with legacy Excel such as Excel 2013.

You could try this (adjust the number of 8th columns, here I've used 2):
For a single result
=IF(OR(
INDEX(13:13,,SEQUENCE(,2,COLUMN(Y1),8)) 
< INDEX(5:5,,SEQUENCE(,2,COLUMN(Y1),8))),"Yes","No")

=WENN(ODER(
INDEX(13:13;;SEQUENCE(;2;SPALTE(Y1);8)
< INDEX(5:5;;SEQUENCE(;2;SPALTE(Y1);8)));"Yes";"No")

I prefer to use variables with LET and functions - here we could get the results for comparing other rows as well:
=LET(
    num_columns, 2,
    columns, SEQUENCE(, num_columns, COLUMN(Y1), 8),
    row_5, INDEX(5:5, , columns),
    num_rows, 5,
    lower_than_row_5, LAMBDA(r,
        IF(OR(INDEX(1:20, r, columns) < row_5), "Yes", "No")
    ),
    MAP(SEQUENCE(num_rows, , 13), lower_than_row_5)
)


=LET(
    num_columns; 2;
    columns; SEQUENZ(; num_columns; SPALTE(Y1); 8);
    row_5; INDEX(5:5; ; columns);
    num_rows; 5;
    lower_than_row_5; LAMBDA(r;
        WENN(ODER(INDEX(1:20; r; columns) < row_5); "Yes"; "No")
    );
    MAP(SEQUENZ(num_rows; ; 13); lower_than_row_5)
)

I hope the translation is correct - please let me know whether it works with your data.

